# using kafka with schema-registry, in app with multiple topics and SubjectNameStrategy

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

To begin with, I have found a way how to do this, more or less. But it's *really* bad code. So I'm looking for suggestions how to solve this better if this approach exist.

To lay something to work with. Assume you have app, which sends `avro` to *n* topics and uses schema registry. Assume(at first) that you don't want to use avro unions, since they bring some issues along. *N-1* topics are easy, 1 schema per topic. But then, you have data, you need to send **in order**, which means 1 topic and specified group key, but these data don't have same schema. So to do that, you need to register multiple schema per that topic in schema registry, which implies use of `key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy` or similar. And here it becomes ugly.

But that setting is per schema registry instance, *so* you have to declare 2(or more) schema registry instances, one per each SubjectNameStrategy key/value combination. This will work.

But then, according to documentation, RecordNameStrategy is java-platform only (!), so if you would like to create service, which is not language specific (which you would most probably like to do in 2021 ...), you cannot use RecordNameStrategy.

So if you cannot use RecordNameStrategy, and for some reason you still want to use avro and schema registry, IIUC you have no other choice, than to use avro unions on top level, and use defaut `TopicNameStrategy`, which is fine now, since you have single unioned schema. But top-level unions weren't nice to me in past, since deserializer don't know, naturally, which type would you like to deserialize from the data. So theoretically a way out of this could be using say Cloudevents standard(or something similar), setting cloudevent `type` attribute in respect to which type from union was used to serialize data, and then have type->deserializer map, to be able to pick correct deserializer for avro-encoded data in received cloudevents message. This will work, and not only for java.

So to wrap up, here are 2 generally described solutions to very simple problem. But to be honest, these seems extremely complicated for widely accepted solution (avro/schema-registry). I'd like to know, if there is easier way through this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common theme, particularly in CQRS-like systems in which commands may be ordered (eg create before update or delete etc).  In these cases, using Kafka, it's often not desirable to publish the messages over multiple topics.  You are correct that there are two solutions for sending messages with multiple schemas on the same topic: either a top-level union in the avro schema, or multiple schemas per topic.

You say you don't want to use top-level unions in the schema, so I'll address the case of multiple schemas per topic.  You are correct that this excludes the use of any subject naming strategy that includes only the topic name to define the subject.  So `TopicNameStrategy` is out.

> But then, according to documentation, RecordNameStrategy is java-platform only (!), so if you would like to create service, which is not language specific (which you would most probably like to do in 2021 ...), you cannot use RecordNameStrategy.

This is worthy of some clarification.... In the confluent way of things, the 'schema-registry aware avro serializers' first register your writer schema in the registry against a subject name to obtain a schema id.  They then prefix your avro bytes with that schema id before publishing to kafka.  See the 'Confluent Wire Format' at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format.

So the subject naming is a choice in the serializer library; the deserializer just resolves a schema by the id prefixing the kafka message.  The confluent Java serializers make this subject naming configurable and define strategies `TopicNameStrategy`, `RecordNameStrategy` and `TopicRecordNameStrategy`.  See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#subject-name-strategy.  The three strategies are conventions for defining 'scopes' over which schemas will be tested for compatibility in the registry (per-topic, per-record, or a combination). You've identified `RecordNameStrategy` fits your use case for having multiple avro schemas per topic.

However, I think your concern about non-Java support for `RecordNameStrategy` can be set aside.  In the serializer, the subject naming is free to be implemented however the serializer developer chooses.  Having worked on this stuff in Java, Python, Go and NodeJS, I've experienced some variety in how third-party serializers work in this regard.  Nevertheless, working non-Java libs do exist.

If all else fails, you can write your own 'schema-registry aware serializer' that registers the schema with your chosen subject name prior to encoding the confluent wire-format for Kafka.  I've had happy outcomes from other tooling by keeping to one of the well-known confluent strategies, so I can recommend mimicking them.

Comment: (1)Thanks for you reply! I didn't expect one to such long question! (2) wire format! I finally learned its name. I've kept reading about confluent ID etc. (3) so IIUC the naming strategy is kinda pointless, until you search for schema and it's version by subject name using rest OR I have schema compatibility tests set? Since otherwise, even if I use TopicNameStrategy in this scenario, there will be just N versions of key/value schema, each getting it's own schemaID

Comment: (4) since (IIUC) strategy is only for schema compatibility tests and nicer grouping so that we can fetch it from rest, deserializer typically dont use it, and thus java-only limitation (as [maybe incorrectly] mentioned in documentation) for RecordNameStrategy effectively applies only to producer, or to be more specific, to the code who registers the schema. So readers are totally not affected by this (5) sorry for long text and I really appreciate your long answer. I hope I got it right in comments 3 and 4. Thanks again!